# Python script to update remote machines

Tags: python, linux

I'm attempting my first foray into creating a Python script that will automate software updates remotely to our machines.  What it needs to do:

- Telnet into machine
- Run a command that changes the machine's IP address (gives the machines external access for downloading from an online repo)
- Reboot machine for changes to take effect
- Run a command that points to a directory, then executes the command
- Once completed, change the IP address to its original address and reboot

Using python's telnet library, I can get remotely connected to the server and send commands, but I'm stuck on the part that involves rebooting the machine and reconnecting to it automatically.  Is there a way to create a try/catch statement that tries pinging the machine until it gets a reply, or is this not a feasible idea?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: What have you tried, what did work, what didn't? Why? Where is the code you have written so far? Where are you stuck with that and why? ...

Comment: Don't use exceptions for things that will happen regularly.  I would setup a watchdog timer to make sure it doesn't take too long and loop until some ping bounces back or your timer goes off.

Comment: I don't currently have code for reconnecting after sending the reboot command; that's the part I'm stuck on as I don't know how I would devise that code.

Comment: Ping is feasible and you can do it yourself using the socket module and opening and closing a connection to the telnet server. You may get successful connects as the machine goes down, then a period where the connects fail and then a successful connect again when the machine is ready.

Comment: I did some testing with telnetlib and subprocess that seems to work for now.  I was afraid telnetlib would blow up after sending the reboot command, but putting a subprocess to continuously ping the server until it responds and then starting another telnet connection works _so far_